# Prove the number x is positive IFF x>0

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm trying to work on an exercise from a book which asked to prove the above question.

It seems fairly trivial although I cannot be sure if my attempt suffices.

To prove that the number x is positive if x>0:
By the order axiom, for all x in the positive real number implies x>0.

To prove that the number x is positive only if x>0:
x>0 implies x is an element in the positive real number

And so the proof is done.

Comment: What is being used as the definition of a positive number?

Comment: The definition is as
$$x-y\in \mathbb{R}^+$$

Comment: That looks more like a definition of $x>y$; and it seems to presuppose the definition of "$r^+$".

Comment: Would you like to drop me some hints?

Comment: Well actually, I would have thought that $x>0$ would be a reasonable definition of $x$ being positive.  And then since definitions are if and only if statements, your result would follow trivially.  That's why I'm wondering if your source is taking some different angle on what a positive number is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $x>0$ iff $x-0$ is positive. Can you take it from there?

You should be able to get the rest of the way with axioms and definitions, alone.

**Added**: Let me be more explicit.

By definition of the order relation, $x>0$ iff $x-0\in\Bbb R^+.$ We are supposed to *prove* that $x>0$ iff $x\in\Bbb R^+.$ If we could take for granted that $x-0=x,$ then there would be nothing to prove! Given that, I suspect that $$x-0=x\tag{$\star$}$$ is *exactly* what we have to show. We proceed as follows.

By the additive identity axiom, we know that $$x-0=(x-0)+0.\tag1$$ By definition of subtraction, we have $$(x-0)+0:=(x+-0)+0,\tag2$$ where "$-0$" denotes that $b\in\Bbb R$ such that $0+b=b+0=0.$ Then, by associativity of addition, we know that $$(x+-0)+0=x+(-0+0).\tag3$$ By the additive inverse axiom, we have $$x+(-0+0)=x+0,\tag4$$ and by the additive identity axiom, we have $$x+0=x.\tag5$$ Now, putting it all together, we have $$x-0\overset{(1)}{=}(x-0)+0\overset{(2)}{:=}(x+-0)+0\overset{(3)}{=}x+(-0+0)\overset{(4)}{=}x+0\overset{(5)}{=}x,$$ and by transitivity of $=$ we have thus proved $(\star),$ which allows us to complete the desired proof with ease.

**Note**: At this basic level, proofs can be hilariously tricky. The easiest pitfall is to take things for granted that you've known for years (like the fact that $x-0=x$), but haven't yet proved in the context of the course! You really have to keep in mind what axioms, definitions, and results you have available to work with, and try to avoid using anything else.

Comment: On the "only if" part: 
$$x\in \mathbb{R}^+$$ 
By the ordered field axiom, there is a neutral element 0 so that x+(0)=x
$$\text{x-0$\in \mathbb{R}$}\backslash ^+\text{$\Rightarrow $x$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+$$

Comment: True, we have axiomatically that $y+0=y$ for any $y\in\Bbb R.$ Why is $x-0=x,$ though? (It is, but the additive identity axiom isn't enough, on its own, to prove that.) You *can* conclude, for example, that $(x-0)+0=x-0.$

Comment: Why wouldn't the neutral element 0 suffice?

Comment: Because $y+b$ and $y-b$ aren't generally the same thing. They are when $b=0,$ of course, but that isn't an axiom. That's a result of multiple axioms.

Comment: See what you can do with the knowledge that $(x-0)+0$ is positive.

Comment: Suppose$$\text{x$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+\text{and y=0$\in \mathbb{R}$}$$
We show that $$x>0 only if x - 0 \in \mathbb{R}:$$

$$\text{(x-y) = (x-0)=(x-0)+0=x+(0-0)=x$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+\text{ which implies x$>$0}$$

on the "if part"
$$\text{x$>$0 $\Rightarrow $x-0$>$0-0$\Rightarrow $x$>$0$\Rightarrow $x$\in
   $}\mathbb{R}^+\text{by definition of positive real number}$$

Comment: That's pretty much it, for the "only if" part! $$x=x+0=x+(-0+0)=(x+-0)+0=:(x-0)+0=x-0\in\Bbb R^+.$$ Did you notice all the axioms and definitions that got used?

Comment: The axioms used were all axioms from the ordered field.

Comment: Also, there's no need to split it up into two parts. Since $x>0$ iff $x-0\in\Bbb R^+,$ by definition, and since the progression above shows that that $x-0=x,$ then we're done.

Comment: But Suppose I did as the "if" part above, does it look correct?

Comment: Yes, but *which* ordered field axioms were used? (For example, commutativity of multiplication never came into play.) Also, which two definitions were used?

Comment: Well, your "if" part took $x-0=x$ for granted, but as long as you show that first, you're fine.

Comment: The "associative" property from the ordered field axiom was used. The definition of positive reals was also used.

Comment: To show x-0=x
$$x > 0 = x - 0 > 0 - 0 = x + ( -0 + 0) > 0 + ( -0 + 0 ) = (x - 0) + 0 > (0 - 0 ) + 0
         = x > 0$$

Comment: If I followed that correctly, you've shown that $x>0$ iff $x>0.$ Not much help. Yes, associativity was used, as was additive inverse.

Comment: But x>0 implies x is in the set of positive reals so doesn't that imply, by definition of positive reals that x>0 is positive?

Comment: Yes, but **how** does $x>0$ imply that $x$ is positive? That's part of what you're trying to prove, and you still haven't done so, as far as I can tell.

Comment: In the comments above, I outlined a way for you to prove from axioms and a definition that $x-0=x$ for any $x\in\Bbb R.$ Using that result will make proving both implications *very* direct, using only the definition that $x>0$ iff $x-0\in\Bbb R^+.$

Comment: I have expanded my answer to make clearer what I've been attempting to explain. See if it helps. Incidentally, you should ***never*** do things like $$x > 0 = x - 0 > 0 - 0 = x + ( -0 + 0) > 0 + ( -0 + 0 ) = (x - 0) + 0 > (0 - 0 ) + 0 = x > 0.$$ It denotes a compound statement, sometimes referred to as a chain of equalities and inequalities. Namely, it seems to be saying "$x>0,$ $0=x-0,$ $x-0>0-0,$ $0-0=x+(-0+0),$ $x+(-0+0)>0+(-0+0),$ $0+(-0+0)=(x-0)+0,$ $(x-0)+0<(0-0)+0,$ $(0-0)+0=x,$ and $x>0.$" If we wish to say that two statements are equivalent, we should use $\iff$ or "iff," instead.